# Batch file for printing out the results of nslookup on a list

Tags: batch-file, command-line, nslookup

I have a list of domain names that I want to ensure have the IP addresses that my records say that they do.

can I write a batch file that will take the list, run Nslookup on all the names in it, and then print the results in a .txt?

or better yet, actually compare the results to my records to check the results for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a handy batch file I use:

```
    REM @echo off
    del C:\results.txt 2>nul
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (c:\servers.txt) do NSLOOKUP %%a >> c:\results.txt
    exit
```